# How to catch any link that came from upload/ in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5

im new in laravel 5.2, I just want to ask how you can catch a link that came from `uploads` like: `http://sitename.com/uploads/59128.txt`? I want to redirect them to login page if they tried to access any of route or link that came from `uploads/{any filename}`.

Comment: Clarify the question! Do you mean you want to intercept links to files inside a particular folder? Does the file exists on your public folder? Do your files will match the pattern ```/uploads/*.txt```.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve by protecting your route with auth middleware,
make a small `FileController`

```
class FileController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getFile($filename)
    {
        return response()->download(storage_path($filename), null, [], null);
    }
}
```

and then in `routes.php`

`Route::get('file/{filename}', 'FileController@getFile')->where('filename', '^[^/]+$');`

And that's it. Now, your authenticated users can download files from storage folder (but not its subfolders) by calling http://yoursite.com/file/secret.jpg. Add you can use this URL in src attribute of an image tag.

answer's original [source](http://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2015-securing-filesimages)!

Answer (score 0):

@xerwudjohn simple you can't.
When this file is in the public folder, everyone can access it whitout being logged in.
One method I tried for some minutes, create a new route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
   Route::get('/download/{id}', 'DownloadController@showFile');
});
```

create the function showFile in the DonwloadController

```
public function showFile($id)
{
    return redirect('/image/'.$id.'.txt');
}
```

or use a Model to read uniqueIds out of any table and get the realfile name.
Cheers